# How was information shared between different platforms before XML was invented?

Tags: xml

I was reading about the XXE vulnerability on TryHackMe and I came across this:

> XML simplifies data sharing between various systems because of its platform-independent nature. XML data doesn’t require any conversion when transferred between different systems.

How did XML simplify this data sharing? Why wasn't it "simple" before XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lots of different technologies and standards were (and are still) used.

- CSV was very popular for application setting.
- Custom text files and proprietary binary files were used extensively.
- [SGML](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Generalized_Markup_Language) is a standard use since the 80s.
- [GML](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Generalized_Markup_Language) is even older and was used by IBM.
- [LaTex](https://www.latex-project.org/) is very popular is the scientific community.
- [COBRA](https://www.omg.org/corba/) architecture was popular for internet communication as well as many proprietary protocols.

I personally used CSV and worked with binary files and DAT files.

Comment: I forgot to upvote it and accept it as an answer, my bad. Personally I find it more than enough. I guess it's the purists that want perfection in everything SO will downvote it..